# GETTING A WEB URL FROM THE DATABASE AND EMBEDDING IT ON MY PAGE

Tags: php, html, mysql

Thank you guys. I am designing a system where by the admin registers a newspaper and it's URL so that when a user chooses say Newspaper X, the webpage is embedded and loads. 
I have used an iframe but there is a problem.
Whenever I try to pick the webpage, it can't load even when there is an internet connection.
It shows the link like this:

Springs/www.newsx.com WASN'T FOUND. Remember, Springs is just my project folder saved in my www folder...on my C partition.

Tried echoing the URL and it brings www.newsx.com, I don't know why it loads with "Springs" first.

Newsx.com is just a specimen site. Please help me, don't roast me. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're referencing the links as `www.`..., instead of `http://www.`...

Answer (score 0):

iainn's comment is cryptic but correct: If you don't add the protocol, the browser will think it's a relative path.

So if you are on `C:\Springs\test.php`, the url `www.newsx.com` will be interpreted as `C:\Sprints\www.newsx.com`.

Your code could automatically add `http:\\` if it is not there, but since some sites have `http` where others have `https`, you're probably best off by explicitly storing that information.